# ERROR collecting test session при запуске тестов из make.file

Tags: python, python-3.x, makefile, pytest

Проект https://gitlab.com/nanuchi/gitlab-cicd-crash-course.

В make.file данного проекта есть задача, при которой возникает ошибка:

> ERROR collecting test session
> _______________________________________________________ /usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/**init**.py:126: in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) :1050: in _gcd_import
> ??? :1027: in _find_and_load
> ??? :1006: in _find_and_load_unlocked
> ??? :688: in _load_unlocked
> ??? src/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:161:
> in exec_module
> source_stat, co = _rewrite_test(fn, self.config) src/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:356:
> in *rewrite_test
> co = compile(tree, fn*, "exec", dont_inherit=True) E   TypeError: required field "lineno" missing from alias
> ========================================================= short test summary info
> ========================================================== ERROR  - TypeError: required field "lineno" missing from alias
> !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1
> error during collection
> !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
SRC_DIR := src
test: venv  ##  Unit tests for Flask app
    . $(SRC_DIR)/.venv/bin/activate \
    && pytest -v
```

Тест пытаюсь запускать в дистрибутиве Ubuntu WSL2

```
python3 --version
```

> Python 3.10.12

```
 make --version
```

> GNU Make 4.3 Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu Copyright (C) 1988-2020
> Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or
> later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html This is free software: you
> are free to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the
> extent permitted by law.

Установил пакет pytest:

```
pip install -U pytest
```

> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not
> writeable Requirement already satisfied: pytest in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (7.4.0) Collecting pytest
> Downloading pytest-7.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (324 kB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 324.2/324.2 KB 2.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00 Requirement already satisfied: packaging in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pytest) (23.1) Requirement
> already satisfied: exceptiongroup>=1.0.0rc8 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pytest) (1.1.3)
> Requirement already satisfied: tomli>=1.0.0 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pytest) (2.0.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: pluggy<2.0,>=0.12 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pytest) (1.3.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: iniconfig in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pytest) (2.0.0) Installing
> collected packages: pytest   Attempting uninstall: pytest
> Found existing installation: pytest 7.4.0
> Uninstalling pytest-7.4.0:
> Successfully uninstalled pytest-7.4.0 Successfully installed pytest-7.4.1

Comment: Вот это читали? Там несколько вариантов решения проблемы. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69528842/an-error-while-trying-to-execute-tests-on-python-3-10-with-pytest

Comment: @CrazyElf, да кроме ```property remove --dev pytest && property add --dev pytest``` - линукс не знает таких команд и ```python3 setup.py pytest ``` - no such file